# MySQL indexes to SQL SErver

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have the following script that I want to convert to SQL Server, but how?

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uri VARBINARY(1000),
    INDEX(uri(100))
);
```

How does this index looks like in MSSQL??

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    uri VARBINARY(1000),
    --INDEX ???
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) doesn't have an inline index creation clause in its `create table` syntax. However, you can do it afterwards:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    uri VARBINARY(1000),
);

CREATE INDEX my_table_uri_ind ON mytable(uri);
```

EDIT:
To address the comment below, you can use [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) to gain the effect of indexing only part of your `uri`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    uri VARBINARY(1000),
    uri100 AS SUBSTRING (uri, 1, 100)
);

CREATE INDEX my_table_uri_ind ON mytable(uri100);
```

Comment: Okay. But ain't it possible to do CREATE INDEX my_table_uri_ind ON mytable(uri(100)) in some way??

Comment: @grmihel no. An index goes over the full field. And indices on binary - no. Why does whover programemd that think a URI is varbinary to start with?

Comment: @TomTom I don't know. But since its a mapping fom MySQL to SQL on a bigger system, I'm trying to map as close as 1:1 as I can do. if I index uri and another var (like varchar int (100)), then the index will be too big... Any ideas how to get past this?

Comment: Yes. Redesign the mapping. Map on a clculated field. YOur decision and your trade offs.

Comment: @grmihel See my edit above about using calculated columns to simulate the effect of mysql's `uri(100)`.